# Changing design to avoid dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I need some ideas on how to optimize some code that works more or less as follows:

```
struct Notifier
{
  void compute
  {
    for(auto& n : nodes_)
    {
      n->compute(inputs_);
    }
  }

  void add_input(input* i)
  {
    inputs_.push_back(i);
  }
  vector<input*> inputs_;
  vector<node*>  nodes_;
};

struct Node
{
  virtual void compute(vector<input*>& inputs) = 0;
};

struct GraphUpdate
{
  virtual ~GraphUpdate = {}
};

struct DerivedGraphUpdate : public GraphUpdate
{
  //specific business logic
};

struct DerivedGraphUpdate2 : public GraphUpdate
{
  //specific business logic
};

struct DerivedNode : public Node
{
  void compute(vector<input*>& inputs_) override
  {
    for(auto i : inputs_)
    {
        auto update = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedGraphUpdate>(i->getLastUpdate());
        if(update){
          //process
        }
        auto update = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedGraphUpdate2>(i->getLastUpdate());
        if(update){
          //process
        }
        //...
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see `GraphUpdate` is there just to do some basic type erasure, and everything is processed through `dynamic_pointer_casts`.
I am trying to get my head around this problem and try to change it. Ideally I would like the `Notifier` to notify on the derived classes, such that instead of having a gigantic `compute` method that has to switch on the types using the pretty horrible `dynamic_pointer_cast`, it could just have some methods as follows:

```
void handle(DerivedGraphUpdate* d);
void handle(DerivedGraphUpdate2* d);
```

I don't mind that much the big `compute` method, but I'd like to have a way to get rid of the `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

To be noted, the `Notifier` doesn't have any knowledge of the actual derived `Input` and `GraphUpdate` types, because it was coded to be generic and it's actually on a separate codebase.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever "`//process`" does, just put it in a virtual method that's defined in each subclass, and call the virtual method in the `for` loop. Mission accomplished. This is exactly what virtual methods are for.

Comment: Look into the visitor pattern. I have a blog post on it (although I call it double dispatch): https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/stop-reimplementing-the-virtual-table-and-start-using-double-dispatch/

Comment: `//process` just gets state from each `DerivedGraphUpdate` and computes some values. 
`GraphUpdate`  don't know about `DerivedNode`

Comment: Doesn't have to. To quote Sam Varshavchik, "This is exactly what virtual methods are for."

Comment: @AndyG thanks, I'll have a look, it looks promising and potentially that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

> Changing design to avoid dynamic_cast

Use a virtual function:

```
struct GraphUpdate
{
    virtual void process() = 0;
```

---

> ```
> virtual ~GraphUpdate = {}
> ```

Use `= default;` instead.